# Blackberry custom button that looks like the default button

Tags: blackberry

I've implemented a custom button using the example code seen here, posted by Bikas:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/fixedwidth-buttonField-cannot-center-text/m-p/239116

However, I'd like for the button to look like the default Blackberry button.

How would I modify the paint method shown below to look like the default button?

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    int w = width - (leftMargin + rightMargin);
    int h = height - (topMargin + bottomMargin);        

    if(isFocus() == false)
    {
        graphics.setColor(backgroundColorNormal);
        graphics.fillRoundRect(leftMargin, topMargin, w, h, 6, 6);
        graphics.setColor(0x00394142);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(leftMargin, topMargin, w, h, 6, 6);
        graphics.drawText(label,  labelTopLeftPoint.x, labelTopLeftPoint.y);               
    }
    else
    {            
        graphics.setColor(backgroundColorOnFocus);
        graphics.fillRoundRect(leftMargin, topMargin, w, h, 6, 6);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(leftMargin, topMargin, w, h, 6, 6);

        graphics.setColor(0x00ffffff);
        graphics.drawText(label,  labelTopLeftPoint.x, labelTopLeftPoint.y);
    }        
}
```

I can't seem to find this information anywhere when searching.

Thank you for your help,
Stateful

Comment: Do the later posts in that Blackberry forum thread by haemishg that extend ButtonField work?  That seems like the "right" way to get the button to draw the same as the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either Eclipse or the legacy JDE, add a unmodified ButtonField to your application, place a breakpoint after you have initialized the object and inspect the details of the unmodified ButtonField to get the properties you need.